# How to run as .jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have been programming for about 6 months now, and I have just started using eclipse to export jar files (I was using cmd before). I know that you can use the `export function` to export to a `jar`, but I am wondering if there is a way to make eclipse do that automatically when I click the `Run` button. I have done some *googleing*, and it looks like I need to use either the `Run Configuration`, or the `External Tools`, but I have not found any step-by-step instructions or examples on how to set it up to export to a jar and then run it, and I am too much of a noob (not a n00b, there is a difference) still to be able to figure it out on my own. An example would be nice, and step-by-step would be better, but I will try not to be picky.Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Why would you want this? Don't you like testing your programs before exporting them?

Comment: The reason I would like to export to jar to test my program is because it has some code that only works if it is inside of a jar ex. Unzipping files form a jar, Listing files inside of a jar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already used the command line, you can enter the same configuration in the External Tool Configuration (using the dropdown arrow). Double click on Program on the left side to create a new configuration. Then you simply need to provide the working directory and the arguments.

This page gives an example with pictures : http://developer4life.blogspot.be/2012/08/save-time-with-eclipse-external-tools.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That looks right, but what arguments would I put to make it compile to a jar?

Comment: Just use the same as the one you used on the command line. Eclipse will use the exact same executable under the hood.